# Black mask: css transition applied with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

### My code

```js
function obscure(){
    var content = document.getElementById("oscura");
 content.style.display="";
 content.style.opacity = 0;
 content.style.transition = "opacity 3s";
 content.style.opacity = 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div id="oscura" style="top:0; min-width:100%; min-height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:9; background-color:black; display:none; opacity:1;"></div>
<button onclick="obscure();">obscure</button>
<div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras viverra imperdiet libero, in iaculis nulla fermentum vel. Fusce sit amet nulla rhoncus, porttitor tellus venenatis, pellentesque augue. Morbi orci massa, ultricies a lacinia non, luctus eget nunc. Vestibulum ornare placerat arcu, sit amet accumsan est tristique in. Quisque nec orci sit amet lorem pharetra vestibulum. Curabitur ac dui rutrum, pretium massa nec, lobortis dolor. Proin dictum non lacus ac bibendum. Suspendisse hendrerit quam tempor fringilla rhoncus. Quisque lectus elit, fermentum at condimentum at, molestie eget lectus. Etiam at urna nec ex sagittis porttitor. Mauris scelerisque, nibh vitae placerat imperdiet, tellus lorem semper sem, at dignissim lorem dui sed est. Nunc iaculis laoreet sem, sed malesuada turpis vehicula at. Vestibulum consequat leo eget scelerisque maximus. Vivamus quis arcu et urna iaculis facilisis. Donec sit amet risus lectus.
</div>
```

### What it should do

Apply a black mask with a transition which should last 3 seconds

### What isn't working

The mask is applied correctly, but without the transition

### Where I tested my code

On the latest versions of chrome and firefox for windows 10

### My question

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is there any issue with defining the transition in a CSS file?

Comment: @Streetlamp no, there isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you have a bit messed order of setting opacity, z-index and display: in inline style it is fully opaque with display:none and unset transition; and setting other display, transition and opacity in via JS. Iʼm not sure it could work this way (changing some transitionable CSS property value, changing `transition` property and finally changing first property value and have working transition), but after slight simplification with transition set initially and with allways-display-block-layer-hidden-behind-document it does work, like this:

```js
function obscure(on) {
  var content = document.getElementById("oscura");
  content.style.opacity = on ? 0.5 : 0;
  content.style.zIndex = on ? 9 : -1;
}
```

```css
#oscura {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="oscura" onclick="obscure(false);"></div>
<button onclick="obscure(true);">obscure</button>
<div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras viverra imperdiet libero, in iaculis nulla fermentum vel. Fusce sit amet nulla rhoncus, porttitor tellus venenatis, pellentesque augue. Morbi orci massa, ultricies a lacinia non, luctus eget
  nunc. Vestibulum ornare placerat arcu, sit amet accumsan est tristique in. Quisque nec orci sit amet lorem pharetra vestibulum. Curabitur ac dui rutrum, pretium massa nec, lobortis dolor. Proin dictum non lacus ac bibendum. Suspendisse hendrerit quam
  tempor fringilla rhoncus. Quisque lectus elit, fermentum at condimentum at, molestie eget lectus. Etiam at urna nec ex sagittis porttitor. Mauris scelerisque, nibh vitae placerat imperdiet, tellus lorem semper sem, at dignissim lorem dui sed est. Nunc
  iaculis laoreet sem, sed malesuada turpis vehicula at. Vestibulum consequat leo eget scelerisque maximus. Vivamus quis arcu et urna iaculis facilisis. Donec sit amet risus lectus.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `css` `animation`

```js
function obscure(){
    var content = document.getElementById("oscura");
    content.className = "mask";
    content.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#oscura {
  top:0;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  /* set `opacity` to complete `opacity` at `keyframes` */
  opacity:0.4; 
  z-Index:9;
  background-color:black;
  display:none;
}

.mask {
  animation: mask 3s;
  -webkit-animation: mask 3s;
}

@keyframes mask {
  from {    
    opacity:0.0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:0.4;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mask {
  from {    
    opacity:0.0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:0.4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="oscura" style=""></div>
<button onclick="obscure();">obscure</button>
<div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras viverra imperdiet libero, in iaculis nulla fermentum vel. Fusce sit amet nulla rhoncus, porttitor tellus venenatis, pellentesque augue. Morbi orci massa, ultricies a lacinia non, luctus eget nunc. Vestibulum ornare placerat arcu, sit amet accumsan est tristique in. Quisque nec orci sit amet lorem pharetra vestibulum. Curabitur ac dui rutrum, pretium massa nec, lobortis dolor. Proin dictum non lacus ac bibendum. Suspendisse hendrerit quam tempor fringilla rhoncus. Quisque lectus elit, fermentum at condimentum at, molestie eget lectus. Etiam at urna nec ex sagittis porttitor. Mauris scelerisque, nibh vitae placerat imperdiet, tellus lorem semper sem, at dignissim lorem dui sed est. Nunc iaculis laoreet sem, sed malesuada turpis vehicula at. Vestibulum consequat leo eget scelerisque maximus. Vivamus quis arcu et urna iaculis facilisis. Donec sit amet risus lectus.
</div>
```